# Sorting arrays using if-else statement creates new and unwanted keys with numeric values

Tags: php, html, arrays, if-statement, associative-array

Why does this code create new keys with numeric values when attempting to sort the initial array with an if-else statement?

```
    <?php
 $url = file_get_contents("http://i.turner.ncaa.com/sites/default/files/external/test/scoreboard.json");
 $turnerNCAAJsonObject = json_decode($url,true);

for ($n = 0; $n <= count($turnerNCAAJsonObject); $n++) {
    if(isset($turnerNCAAJsonObject[$n][state]) && $turnerNCAAJsonObject[$n][state] == 'final') {
        echo "this is the final game";
    }elseif (isset($turnerNCAAJsonObject[$n][state]) && $turnerNCAAJsonObject[$n][state] == 'pre') {
        echo "this is a pre-game";
    }elseif ($turnerNCAAJsonObject[$n][state] == 'live') {
        $liveGames[] = array_push($liveGames, $turnerNCAAJsonObject[$n]);
    }
}
print_r($liveGames);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use `$liveGames[]` you assign new keys, so replace this line:

```
$liveGames[] = array_push($liveGames, $turnerNCAAJsonObject[$n]);
```

with this:

```
array_push($liveGames, $turnerNCAAJsonObject[$n]);
```